# How to SSH into Docker container runs on remote PC?

Tags: azure, docker, ssh, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on an Azure server and trying to deploy a Docker container in it. What I want to do is run a Jupyter Notebook in that Docker container and make a connection to that Jupyter with my local pc. I know how to connect a Jupyter that runs on a Docker container in local pc. However I don't know if it is possible to connect a remote Docker container that runs in an Azure machine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you connecting if you are running in local? You have no option to bash into remote container directly. there will be workaround if you have any client for Jupyter

Comment: I don't want to bash into remote container. When you do `docker run --net=host -d -p 8888:8888 jupyter_image` and start Jupyter Notebook in that container, you can acces to that notebook (runs in container) with entering "http://localhost:8888/some_token" in your local pc browser. This means I could see some Jupyter interface if I had desktop view of my Azure machine. I am asking that is it possible to port that 8888 port of Azure machine to my laptop pc so that I can see the interface of Jupyter runs in container.

Comment: This is very simple to access open port 8888 to your network or anywhere from inbound rule of the azure machine. Then you can access using public IP of your machine. You can access using ip_address:8888 from your local machine

Comment: @JinnaBalu thanks for your comment I realised that this was a stupid question to ask. It works now I forwarded `8888` port of Azure machine to `8001` port of my laptop. I can reach to Jupyter that runs on container with writing `localhost:8001` on my laptop's browser. Thanks for your interest!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to connect into the container to see the configuration in it. You can make a bash connect into the Azure container. Then you can exec command such as you are in the container OS. And you also can see the interface of Jupyter runs in Azure container.

For more details, you can read the document [Execute a command in a running Azure container instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-exec).

Comment: I solved the issue with "port forwarding" method using Putty. However that's a good source I can use. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @doruk.sonmez I'm glad to hear that.